# How can I make a messagebox or textbox pop up when a specific cell is double clicked in my DataGrid in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid, I'm using C# WPF. I want to find a way so that when a user double clicks a cell that is in my very last column that a Textbox pops up and displays all of the content in that specific cell. Is there anyway to possibly do this? You would think there would be a way I could just be like

`if (myDataGridObj.cellselected[i] is in this Column)`

```
{ 
  do stuff
}
```

I basically want to give back the content of that specific cell when a user double clicks on that specific cell. I don't wwant anything to pop up though unless that specific cell falls under a certain column name and is clicked. I  only want to give back that cell's content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. We need to handle MouseDoubleClickEvent for cells.
2. Check if double-click happens in our desired cell.
3. Then we need to show a TextBox over our Grid with cell's data.
4. If we click anywhere over our Grid outside TextBox, TextBox should be hidden.

In this example, Double-clicking last column which is Address column, TextBox is displayed.

Below code can be used as is :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfDataControls.DataGrid._32792409.Win32792409"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Win32792409" Height="329.323" Width="568.421">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="192*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="107*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="87*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="53*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="DgrdEmployees"  PreviewMouseDown="Grid_PreviewMouseDown" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="148" Width="305" LoadingRow="DgrdEmployees_LoadingRow" />
        <TextBox x:Name="TbDgrdCellContent" Visibility="Hidden" Width="200" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,59,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FFFFF3F3" BorderThickness="4"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;

using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfDataControls.DataGrid._32792409
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Win32792409.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Win32792409 : Window
    {
        public Win32792409()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(DataStore.Employees);
            DgrdEmployees.ItemsSource = view;
        }

        private void Grid_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            TbDgrdCellContent.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;            
        }

        private void DgrdEmployees_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
        {
            MouseButtonEventHandler handler = new MouseButtonEventHandler(DgrdCell_MouseDoubleClick);
            e.Row.AddHandler(DataGridCell.MouseDoubleClickEvent, handler);
        }

        private void DgrdCell_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Double click");

            DataGridCellInfo cellInfo = DgrdEmployees.CurrentCell;
            DataGridColumn col = cellInfo.Column;

            if (DgrdEmployees.Columns.IndexOf(col) < DgrdEmployees.Columns.Count - 1) return;

            FrameworkElement content = col.GetCellContent(cellInfo.Item);

            TbDgrdCellContent.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            TbDgrdCellContent.Text = ((TextBox)content).Text;
            TbDgrdCellContent.Focus();
        }

    }

    public class DataStore
    {
        static ObservableCollection<Employee> _employees;
        public static ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get { return _employees; } set { _employees = value; } }

        static DataStore() {
            _employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
            _employees.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Anjum", Address = "nizamuddin" });
            _employees.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Ashok", Address = "bharat nagar" });
            _employees.Add(new Employee() { Name = "BAshok", Address = "bharat nagar" });
            _employees.Add(new Employee() { Name = "DAshok", Address = "bharat nagar" });
            _employees.Add(new Employee() { Name = "TAshok", Address = "bharat nagar" });
            _employees.Add(new Employee() { Name = "GAshok", Address = "bharat nagar" });

        }

    }

    public class Employee {

        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Address { get; set; }        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a separate window dialog? Like so:

```
   <Window x:Class="MyDialog">
       <StackPanel>
           <TextBlock Text="" />
           <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" />
           <Button Content="Done" Click="DoneButton_Click" />
       </StackPanel>
   </Window>
```

And now you can have a simple code behind it:

```
partial class MyDialog : Window {

    public MyDialog(String text) {
        InitializeComponent();
        DialogText = text;
    }

    public string DialogText {
        get { return MyTextBox.Text; }
        set { MyTextBox.Text = value; }
    }

    private void DoneButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = true;
    }
}
```

And on your onDoubleClick (or whatever is called when you cell is double clicked,) you can create a new dialog and set the text for the textbox.

```
var dialog = new MyDialog("your content here");
dialog.ShowDialog();
```